# How to find the start time and end time of an event in python?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, data-science, data-analysis

I have a data frame consists of column 1 i.e event and column 2 is Datetime:

Sample data

```
 Event   Time
    0   2020-02-12 11:00:00
    0   2020-02-12 11:30:00
    2   2020-02-12 12:00:00
    1   2020-02-12 12:30:00
    0   2020-02-12 13:00:00
    0   2020-02-12 13:30:00
    0   2020-02-12 14:00:00
    1   2020-02-12 14:30:00
    0   2020-02-12 15:00:00
    0   2020-02-12 15:30:00
```

And I want to find start time and end time of each event:

Desired Data

```
 Event  EventStartTime  EventEndTime
    0   2020-02-12 11:00:00 2020-02-12 12:00:00
    2   2020-02-12 12:00:00 2020-02-12 12:30:00
    1   2020-02-12 12:30:00 2020-02-12 13:00:00
    0   2020-02-12 13:00:00 2020-02-12 14:30:00
    1   2020-02-12 14:30:00 2020-02-12 15:00:00
```

Note: EventEndTime is time when the event changes the value say from value 1 to got change to 0 or any other value or vice versa

Comment: paste the data in your question and dont link an image

Comment: How do you distinguish between a start and an end? Are events with the same number guaranteed to not overlap?

Comment: @Błotosmętek start is when 1st time the event started and end time when the value of event changes to some other value. Check the images of data and desired output data

Comment: @luigigi pasted

Comment: Your example makes no sense to me. For example, why `2   1   2020-02-12 **13:00:00** 2020-02-12 13:00:00` if `3   1   2020-02-12 **12:30:00**`?

Comment: please make sure the expected output is correct

Comment: @Błotosmętek now check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the dataframe is `data`:

```
current_event = None
result = []
for event, time in zip(data['Event'], data['Time']):
    if event != current_event:
        if current_event is not None:
            result.append([current_event, start_time, time])
        current_event, start_time = event, time
data = pandas.DataFrame(result, columns=['Event','EventStartTime','EventEndTime'])
```

The trick is to save your event number; if the next event number is not the same as the saved one, the saved one has to be ended and a new one started.

Comment: hey if I want to group by some category first and then itterate through that loop then what I suppose to do?   @Błotosmętek

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that can get the results without a for loop. I assume that the input data is read into a dataframe called df:

```
# Initialize the output df
dfout = pd.DataFrame()
dfout['Event'] = df['Event']
dfout['EventStartTime'] = df['Time']
```

Now, I create a variable called 'change' that tells you whether the event changed.

```
dfout['change'] = df['Event'].diff()
```

This is how dfout looks now:

```
   Event       EventStartTime  change
0      0  2020-02-12 11:00:00     NaN
1      0  2020-02-12 11:30:00     0.0
2      2  2020-02-12 12:00:00     2.0
3      1  2020-02-12 12:30:00    -1.0
4      0  2020-02-12 13:00:00    -1.0
5      0  2020-02-12 13:30:00     0.0
6      0  2020-02-12 14:00:00     0.0
7      1  2020-02-12 14:30:00     1.0
8      0  2020-02-12 15:00:00    -1.0
9      0  2020-02-12 15:30:00     0.0
```

Now, I go on to remove the rows where the event did not change:

```
dfout = dfout.loc[dfout['change'] !=0 ,:]
```

This will now leave me with rows where the event has changed.

Next, the event end time of the current event is the start time of the next event.

```
dfout['EventEndTime'] = dfout['EventStartTime'].shift(-1)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
   Event       EventStartTime  change         EventEndTime
0      0  2020-02-12 11:00:00     NaN  2020-02-12 12:00:00
2      2  2020-02-12 12:00:00     2.0  2020-02-12 12:30:00
3      1  2020-02-12 12:30:00    -1.0  2020-02-12 13:00:00
4      0  2020-02-12 13:00:00    -1.0  2020-02-12 14:30:00
7      1  2020-02-12 14:30:00     1.0  2020-02-12 15:00:00
8      0  2020-02-12 15:00:00    -1.0                  NaN
```

You may chose to remove the 'change' column and also the last row if not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Use group by and agg to get the output in desired format.

```
df =pd.DataFrame([['0',11],['1',12],['1',13],['0',15],['1',16],['3',11]],columns=['Event','Time'] )
df.groupby(['Event']).agg(['first','last']).rename(columns={'first':'start-event','last':'end-event'})
```

Output:

```
Event start-event   end-event   
0      11           15
1      12           16
3      11           11
```

Comment: Output not same as expected by op.

Comment: This is not a desired output.