# How to find the start time and end time of an event group by class in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a data frame consists of column 1 i.e event and column 2 is Datetime:

Sample data

```
 Class Event    Time
0   A   0   2020-02-19 11:00:00
1   A   0   2020-02-19 11:30:00
2   B   1   2020-02-19 11:00:00
3   B   1   2020-02-19 11:30:00
4   B   0   2020-02-19 12:00:00
5   B   0   2020-02-19 12:30:00
6   A   0   2020-02-19 14:00:00
7   B   1   2020-02-19 13:30:00
8   A   1   2020-02-19 15:00:00
9   B   1   2020-02-19 15:30:00
10  A   0   2020-02-19 15:30:00
11  B   0   2020-02-19 16:00:00
12  A   1   2020-02-19 16:30:00
```

And I want to find start time and end time of each event by Class:
I have tried the below code [from the answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186401/how-to-find-the-start-time-and-end-time-of-an-event-in-python) but I am getting an empty dataframe:

```
current_event = None
result = []
grouped=df.groupby(['Class'])
for name, group in grouped:
    for class, event, time in zip(data['Class'],data['Event'], data['Time']):
        if event != current_event:
           if current_event is not None:
                result.append([Class,current_event, start_time, time])
            class, current_event, start_time = class, event, time
data = pandas.DataFrame(result, columns=['Class','Event','EventStartTime','EventEndTime'])
```

Desired Data

```
    Class   Event   EventStartTime       EventEndTime
0    A        0    2020-02-19 11:00:00  2020-02-19 15:00:00
1    A        1    2020-02-19 15:00:00  2020-02-10 15:30:00
2    A        0    2020-02-19 15:30:00  2020-02-10 16:30:00
3    B        1    2020-02-19 11:00:00  2020-02-10 12:00:00
4    B        0    2020-02-19 12:00:00  2020-02-19 13:30:00
5    B        1    2020-02-19 13:30:00  2020-02-19 16:00:00
```

Note: EventEndTime is time when the event changes the value say from value 1 to got change to 0 or any other value of a particular class

Comment: @luigigi if you look thoroughly, it does make sense. Please go through logic while putting any comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dfg = df.groupby('Class')
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for c,d in dfg:
    dfx = d[~(d.Event == d.shift().Event)]
    dfx['EventEndTime'] = d[~(d.Event == d.shift().Event)].shift(-1)['Time']
    dfx = dfx.dropna()
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, dfx], ignore_index=True)
df_new.columns = ['Class','Event','EventStartTime','EventEndTime']
print(df_new)

  Class  Event      EventStartTime        EventEndTime
0     A      0 2020-02-19 11:00:00 2020-02-19 15:00:00
1     A      1 2020-02-19 15:00:00 2020-02-19 15:30:00
2     A      0 2020-02-19 15:30:00 2020-02-19 16:30:00
3     B      1 2020-02-19 11:00:00 2020-02-19 12:00:00
4     B      0 2020-02-19 12:00:00 2020-02-19 13:30:00
5     B      1 2020-02-19 13:30:00 2020-02-19 16:00:00
```

Comment: what do you mean not desired code? it is the desired output

Comment: Now could you see my desired output again?? I want to group by Class @luigigi