# How to create rows that fill the time between events in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, fill

I am building a data frame for survival analysis starting from 2018-01-01 00:00:00 and ending TODAY. I have two columns with start and end times **only** for the events that ocurred associated with an ID.

However, I need to add rows with the times **between** which the event **was not observed**

Here I show what I have:

```
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State  | ID1 | ID2 | Start_Time          | End_Time            |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-04 04:00:00 | 2019-12-04 19:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-08 06:30:00 | 2019-12-20 10:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-22 11:00:00 | 2019-12-22 23:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-26 08:00:00 | 2019-12-29 16:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA2 | 2018-09-19 08:00:00 | 2018-09-20 04:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA2 | 2018-09-25 16:30:00 | 2018-09-26 23:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA2 | 2018-09-27 01:30:00 | 2018-09-27 10:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And what I need is:

```
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State  | ID1 | ID2 | Start_Time          | End_Time            |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-12-04 04:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-04 04:00:00 | 2019-12-04 19:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-04 19:30:00 | 2019-12-08 06:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-08 06:30:00 | 2019-12-20 10:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-20 10:00:00 | 2019-12-22 11:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-22 11:00:00 | 2019-12-22 23:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-22 23:00:00 | 2019-12-26 08:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-26 08:00:00 | 2019-12-29 16:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 111 | AA1 | 2019-12-29 16:30:00 | TODAY               |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State1 | 112 | AA1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-09-19 08:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA2 | 2018-09-19 08:00:00 | 2018-09-20 04:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA1 | 2018-09-20 04:30:00 | 2018-09-25 16:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA2 | 2018-09-25 16:30:00 | 2018-09-26 23:00:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA1 | 2018-09-26 23:00:00 | 2018-09-27 01:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA2 | 2018-09-27 01:30:00 | 2018-09-27 10:30:00 |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| State2 | 112 | AA2 | 2018-09-27 10:30:00 | TODAY               |
+--------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I have tried this code (borrowed from: [How to find the start time and end time of an event in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186401/how-to-find-the-start-time-and-end-time-of-an-event-in-python)), but it gives me only the sequence of events, not the desired rows and the answer provided by @Fredy Montaño (below):

```
fill_date = []
for item in range(1,df.shape[0],1):
    if (df['End_Time'][item-1] - df['Start_Time'][item]) == 0:
        ""
    else: 
        fill_date.append([df["State"][item-1], df["ID1"][item-1], df["ID2"][item-1], df['End_Time'][item-1],df['Start_Time'][item]])

df_add = pd.DataFrame(fill_date)
df_add.columns = ["State", "ID1", "ID2", 'Start_Time', 'End_Time']

df_output = pd.concat([df[["State", "ID1", "ID2", "Start_Time", "End_Time"]], df_add],axis = 0)
df_output = df_output.sort_values(["State", "ID2", "Start_Time"], ascending=True)
```

I think I have to put a condition over the STATE, ID1 and ID2 variables in order to not to take times from the previous groups.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where is the python you've written so far?

Comment: I put the code above!

Comment: That code doesn't run. Please provide everything we would need to test this ourselves.

Comment: The code is updated. I think I have to put a condition over the categorical variables STATE, ID1 and ID2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution works for you.
I slice the dataframe only to take the dates, but it works for you you can repeat it taking into account the states and ID

```
df = df[['Start_Time', 'End_Time']]

fill_date = []
for item in range(1,df.shape[0],1):
    if df['Start_Time'][item] - df['End_Time'][item-1] == 0:
        ""
    else: 
        fill_date.append([df['End_Time'][item-1],df['Start_Time'][item]])

df_add = pd.DataFrame(fill_date) 
df_add.columns = ['Start_Time', 'End_Time']
```

and finally, I do a concat to join you original dataframe with the new df of dates of not Observed events [dates on squares are the new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h87t0.png)

```
df_final = pd.concat([df,df_add],axis = 0)
df_final.sort_index(0)
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty near to the expected one. However, it brokes up at line 8. It jumps from month 12 to month 9. One think here is that categorical variables as STATE, ID1 and ID2 have to be consider, because they represent different subjects.

Comment: Yes, you right, this small example doesn't take into account the other variables, I think you only have to repeat it iteratively by state, ID1, and ID2.