# Finding start-time and end-time of events in a day - Pandas timeseries - such that end time does not fall into next day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, python-datetime

I have a meteorological timeseries df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['11/10/2017 0:00','11/10/2017 03:00','11/10/2017 06:00','11/10/2017 09:00','11/10/2017 12:00',
                       '11/11/2017 0:00','11/11/2017 03:00','11/11/2017 06:00','11/11/2017 09:00','11/11/2017 12:00',
                      '11/12/2017 00:00','11/12/2017 03:00','11/12/2017 06:00','11/12/2017 09:00','11/12/2017 12:00'],
              'value':[850,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,500,650,780,np.nan,800,350,690,780,np.nan,np.nan]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',errors ='coerce') 
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date)
```

With this dataframe, I am trying to find out **start time** and **end time** of **event**:

```
(df["value"] < 1000)
```

I used solution similar to [How to find the start time and end time of an event in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186401/how-to-find-the-start-time-and-end-time-of-an-event-in-python)
with revised code:

```
current_event = None
result = []
for event, time in zip((df["value"] < 1000), df.index):
    if event != current_event:
        if current_event is not None:
            result.append([current_event, start_time, time - pd.DateOffset(hours = 1, minutes = 30)])
        current_event, start_time = event, time - pd.DateOffset(hours = 1, minutes = 30)
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Event','StartTime','EndTime'])
df
```

**Output is**:

```
   Event           StartTime             EndTime
0   True 2017-11-09 22:30:00 2017-11-10 01:30:00
1  False 2017-11-10 01:30:00 2017-11-10 22:30:00
2   True 2017-11-10 22:30:00 2017-11-11 07:30:00
3  False 2017-11-11 07:30:00 2017-11-11 10:30:00
4   True 2017-11-11 10:30:00 2017-11-12 07:30:00
```

But the **desired ouput** is:
[image]

Desired output differs from the output above:

1. **EndTime** in second row(Index 1) to be **2017-11-10 13:30:00**
2. **EndTime** of fifth row (Index 4 ) to be **2017-11-11 13:30:00**
3. **New row** sixth row(index 5) and 6th

**Logic:**

- Since the timestamps are 3h apart ,an **event** is assumed to start 1 hr and 30 minutes before and end at 1 hr 30 minutes after the timestamp.
- If two consecutive events are similar then they add up like: 1 hr and 30 minutes before the first timestamp till 1 hr and 30 minutes after second timestamp and so on.
- StartTime of first event of the day i.e. at time 00:00 should always be 1 hr 30 minutes before 00:00 timestamp i.e. 22:30 of previous day.
- EndTime of the last event of the day i.e. at time 12:00 should always be 1 hr 30 minutes after the 12:00 timestamp i.e. 13:30 of the same day.

Any prompt help on this issue would be highly appreciated. Tried to fix it desperately but no luck yet.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you've shared your most up-to-date code? Because I'm getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'` around the first instance of `time - pd.DateOffset(hours = 1, minutes = 30)`

Comment: Codes are up- to-date. Firstly, you need to convert index to datetimeindex as follows : 
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',errors 
    ='coerce') 
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date)
    df.drop('date', axis = 1, inplace = True)

Comment: Cool, go ahead and edit that code into your original code block, and I'll try running it again

Comment: @ Kevin , the code has been edited in the original code block..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create output dataframe:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({"Event": df["value"] < 1000,
                    "StartTime": df["date"] - pd.DateOffset(hours=1, minutes=30),
                    "EndTime": df["date"] + pd.DateOffset(hours=1, minutes=30)},
                   index=df.index)
```

```
>>> out
    Event           StartTime             EndTime
0    True 2017-11-09 22:30:00 2017-11-10 01:30:00  # Group 0
1   False 2017-11-10 01:30:00 2017-11-10 04:30:00  # Group 1
2   False 2017-11-10 04:30:00 2017-11-10 07:30:00
3   False 2017-11-10 07:30:00 2017-11-10 10:30:00
4   False 2017-11-10 10:30:00 2017-11-10 13:30:00
5    True 2017-11-10 22:30:00 2017-11-11 01:30:00  # Group 2
6    True 2017-11-11 01:30:00 2017-11-11 04:30:00
7    True 2017-11-11 04:30:00 2017-11-11 07:30:00
8   False 2017-11-11 07:30:00 2017-11-11 10:30:00  # Group 3
9    True 2017-11-11 10:30:00 2017-11-11 13:30:00  # Group 4
10   True 2017-11-11 22:30:00 2017-11-12 01:30:00  # Group 5
11   True 2017-11-12 01:30:00 2017-11-12 04:30:00
12   True 2017-11-12 04:30:00 2017-11-12 07:30:00
13  False 2017-11-12 07:30:00 2017-11-12 10:30:00  # Group 6
14  False 2017-11-12 10:30:00 2017-11-12 13:30:00
```

Define some helper groups:

```
event_group = out["Event"].ne(out["Event"].shift(fill_value=0)).cumsum()
time_group = (out["StartTime"] 
              - out["EndTime"].shift(fill_value=out["StartTime"].iloc[0])
              != pd.Timedelta(0)).cumsum()
```

```
>>> out[["Event"]].assign(EventGroup=event_group,
                          TimeGroup=time_group,
                          Groups=event_group + time_group)
    Event  EventGroup  TimeGroup  Groups
0    True           1          0       1  # Group 0
1   False           2          0       2  # Group 1
2   False           2          0       2
3   False           2          0       2
4   False           2          0       2
5    True           3          1       4  # Group 2
6    True           3          1       4
7    True           3          1       4
8   False           4          1       5  # Group 3
9    True           5          1       6  # Group 4
10   True           5          2       7  # Group 5
11   True           5          2       7
12   True           5          2       7
13  False           6          2       8  # Group 6
14  False           6          2       8
```

Reduce output dataframe:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(out.groupby(event_group + time_group)
                      .apply(lambda g: (g["Event"].iloc[0],
                                        g["StartTime"].iloc[0], 
                                        g["EndTime"].iloc[-1]))
                      .tolist(), columns=["Event", "StartTime", "EndTime"])
```

```
>>> out
   Event           StartTime             EndTime
0   True 2017-11-09 22:30:00 2017-11-10 01:30:00
1  False 2017-11-10 01:30:00 2017-11-10 13:30:00
2   True 2017-11-10 22:30:00 2017-11-11 07:30:00
3  False 2017-11-11 07:30:00 2017-11-11 10:30:00
4   True 2017-11-11 10:30:00 2017-11-11 13:30:00
5   True 2017-11-11 22:30:00 2017-11-12 07:30:00
6  False 2017-11-12 07:30:00 2017-11-12 13:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your kind concern to my problem and solving it very nicely again. Codes are concise and easy to understand for a beginner like me. I highly appreciate your kind help..

Comment: @ Corralien I have posted a question , Can you please help me on this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130863/comparing-two-timeseries-dataframes-based-on-some-conditions-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if numpy has a nice efficient solution for this, but I can think of a way to do it with regular Python types. Your existing code does a good job of grouping measurements by event type, but it seems like you also want to separate groups when measurements are more than three hours apart. This isn't *too* hard to do, using an approach similar to `itertools.groupby`. I separated my implementation out into its own function so it's easier to keep separate from your business logic.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

def groupby_similar(seq, key, delta):
    """like itertools.groupby, but puts two values into the same group as long as their difference is less than or equal to delta."""
    no_item = object()
    prev_item = no_item
    group = []
    for item in seq:
        if prev_item is no_item or key(item) - delta <= key(prev_item):
            group.append(item)
        else:
            yield group
            group = [item]
        prev_item = item
    if group:
        yield group

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['11/10/2017 0:00','11/10/2017 03:00','11/10/2017 06:00','11/10/2017 09:00','11/10/2017 12:00',
                       '11/11/2017 0:00','11/11/2017 03:00','11/11/2017 06:00','11/11/2017 09:00','11/11/2017 12:00',
                      '11/12/2017 00:00','11/12/2017 03:00','11/12/2017 06:00','11/12/2017 09:00','11/12/2017 12:00'],
              'value':[850,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,500,650,780,np.nan,800,350,690,780,np.nan,np.nan]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',errors ='coerce') 
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date)

expected_delta = pd.DateOffset(hours = 3)
events_and_times = zip((df["value"] < 1000), df.index)
result = []
for timechunk in groupby_similar(events_and_times, key=lambda et: et[1], delta=pd.DateOffset(hours=3)):
    for event, group in itertools.groupby(timechunk, key=lambda et: et[0]):
        group = list(group)
        start_time = group[0][1]  - pd.DateOffset(hours=1, minutes=30)
        end_time   = group[-1][1] + pd.DateOffset(hours=1, minutes=30)
        result.append([event, start_time, end_time])

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Event','StartTime','EndTime'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Event           StartTime             EndTime
0   True 2017-11-09 22:30:00 2017-11-10 01:30:00
1  False 2017-11-10 01:30:00 2017-11-10 13:30:00
2   True 2017-11-10 22:30:00 2017-11-11 07:30:00
3  False 2017-11-11 07:30:00 2017-11-11 10:30:00
4   True 2017-11-11 10:30:00 2017-11-11 13:30:00
5   True 2017-11-11 22:30:00 2017-11-12 07:30:00
6  False 2017-11-12 07:30:00 2017-11-12 13:30:00
```

I also replaced the event-grouping recipe you were using from that other post, with `itertools.groupby`, because it has an easier time identifying the final False event.

Comment: @ Kevin ... yes, this is the result I need. high regards for your kind help. Highly appreciate it. Thank you very much.