# comparing two timeseries dataframes based on some conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have two timeseries dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date_1':['10/11/2017 0:00','10/11/2017 03:00','10/11/2017 06:00','10/11/2017 09:00'],
                  'value_1':[5000,1500,np.nan,2000]})

df1['date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date_1.astype(str), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',errors ='coerce') 
df1.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.date_1)
df1.drop('date_1', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

&

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date_2': ['2017-10-11 00:00:00', '2017-10-11 00:30:00','2017-10-11 00:50:00', '2017-10-11 01:20:00',
                             '2017-10-11 01:40:00','2017-10-11 02:20:00','2017-10-11 02:50:00', '2017-10-11 03:00:00',
                             '2017-10-11 03:20:00', '2017-10-11 03:50:00','2017-10-11 04:20:00', '2017-10-11 04:50:00',
                             '2017-10-11 05:20:00', '2017-10-11 05:50:00','2017-10-11 06:00:00', '2017-10-11 06:20:00',
                             '2017-10-11 06:50:00', '2017-10-11 07:20:00','2017-10-11 07:50:00', '2017-10-11 08:20:00',
                             '2017-10-11 08:50:00', '2017-10-11 09:20:00','2017-10-11 09:50:00', '2017-10-11 10:20:00'],

                  'value_2':[1500.0, 2050.0,  np.nan,  2400.0, 
                           2500.0,  2550.0,  2900.0,  np.nan,
                           3200.0,  3500.0,  np.nan,  3600.0,
                           2600.0,  2500.0,  2350.0,  2200.0,
                           np.nan,  2100.0,  np.nan,  2400.0,
                           2600.0,  np.nan,  8000.0,  9000.0]
                    })
df2['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.date_2.astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',errors ='coerce') 
df2.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2.date_2)
df2.drop('date_2', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Both dataframes are observations on the same day but with different time resolution. `df1` has time resolution of `3 hours` whereas `df2` has time resolution of `30 minutes` or less.
I am interested to create a new dataframe `dfx` by comparing above dataframes with certain conditions, and create two columns `count` and `duration` in `dfx`.

- firstly: look at `df_2['value_2']`
- compare `df_2['value_2']` with `df_1['value_1']`
- if `df_2['value_2']<2800` for a timestamp & `df_1['value_1'] >1600` for a timestamp within nearest half of the resolution of `df1` i.e. `01:30` we count the `event` as `1` otherwise `0`.
- e.g. for a timestamps of `df2` `00:00:00 - 01:30:00`  compare `df_2['value_2']` values with
  `df_1['value_1']` at `00:00:00`
- for a timestamps of `df2` `01:31:00 - 03:00:00`  compare `df_2['value_2']` values with
  `df_1['value_1']` at `03:00:00`
- for a timestamps of `df2` `03:00:00 - 04:30:00`  compare `df_2['value_2']` values with
  `df_1['value_1']` at `03:00:00`
- for a timestamps of `df2` `04:31:00 - 06:00:00`  compare `df_2['value_2']` values with
  `df_1['value_1']` at `06:00:00`
  and so on.
  where,
- if `df2['value_2] == np.nan` for a timestamp `t` replace the `nan` value with average of values at timestamps`t-1 & t+1` and then make  the comparison.
- if `df1['value_1] == np.nan` for a timestamp `t` , give the corresponding `count` value 0.

For the `duration` column in `dfx`:
`dfx['duration] = df2.index[i+1] - df2.index[i]`
for `count` on marginal time stamps like `01:20:00`,
`dfx['duration] = (df1.index[i] + 01:30) - df2.index[i]`
where. `df1.index[i]` is the timestamp of `df1` with which comparison of df2 is made.

**Desired output**

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'date_2': ['2017-10-11 00:00:00', '2017-10-11 00:30:00','2017-10-11 00:50:00', '2017-10-11 01:20:00',
                             '2017-10-11 01:40:00','2017-10-11 02:20:00','2017-10-11 02:50:00', '2017-10-11 03:00:00',
                             '2017-10-11 03:20:00', '2017-10-11 03:50:00','2017-10-11 04:20:00', '2017-10-11 04:50:00',
                             '2017-10-11 05:20:00', '2017-10-11 05:50:00','2017-10-11 06:00:00', '2017-10-11 06:20:00',
                             '2017-10-11 06:50:00', '2017-10-11 07:20:00','2017-10-11 07:50:00', '2017-10-11 08:20:00',
                             '2017-10-11 08:50:00', '2017-10-11 09:20:00','2017-10-11 09:50:00', '2017-10-11 10:20:00'],

                  'count':[1, 1,  1,  1, 
                           0,  0,  0, 0,
                           0,  0,  0,  0,
                           0,  0,  0,  0,
                           0,  0,  1,  1,
                           1,  0,  0,  0],
                    
                    'duration':['00:30','00:20','00:30','00:10',
                                '00:00', '00:00', '00:00', '00:00',
                                '00:00', '00:00', '00:00', '00:00',
                                '00:00', '00:00', '00:00', '00:00',
                                '00:00', '00:00', '00:30', '00:30',
                                '00:10', '00:00', '00:00', '00:00']})
                        
dfx['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(dfx.date_2.astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',errors ='coerce') 
dfx.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(dfx.date_2)
dfx.drop('date_2', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

My question has become quite long in spite of my desire to shorten it. Please, bear with it.
I would highly appreciate your kind help.

Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Please abstract out your very problem first and then tell us what you already tried to solve it.

Comment: i think your first step is to ensure a standard time gap for df2. there are algorithms to standardise. tell me a fixed time gap you want for df2 first before we start thinking about other things. i can see if i can help you standardise df2 time gap. for example, do you want 15 minutes or 30 minutes?

Comment: @Joshua thanks for your kind concern... as said by Peter, I am also aware that this platform is not free coding service...I am a student...This is one of my research problem.  But, being novice in coding,  I failed to solve the problem... Otherwise I would not ask... Well, the time resolution of `dfx` is same as that of `df2` and If you go through the line again, I have mentioned time resolution of `df2` is `30 minutes` or **less**. Thanks again!

Comment: @ Joshua we can standardise time gap of 30 minutes., in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data:

```
>>> df1
                     value_1
date_1
2017-10-11 00:00:00   5000.0
2017-10-11 03:00:00   1500.0
2017-10-11 06:00:00   1200.0
2017-10-11 09:00:00      NaN

>>> df2
                     value_2
date_2
2017-10-11 00:00:00   1500.0
2017-10-11 00:30:00   2050.0
2017-10-11 00:50:00      NaN
2017-10-11 01:20:00   2400.0
2017-10-11 01:40:00   2500.0
...
2017-10-11 08:20:00   2400.0
2017-10-11 08:50:00   2600.0
2017-10-11 09:20:00      NaN
2017-10-11 09:50:00   8000.0
2017-10-11 10:20:00   9000.0
```

1. Fill `NaN` value from df2 by linear interpolation between `t-1` and `t+1`:

```
df2['value_2'] = df2['value_2'].interpolate()
```

2. Create an interval from df1 according to your rules:

```
ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(
         list(zip(df1.index - pd.DateOffset(hours=1, minutes=29),
                  df1.index + pd.DateOffset(hours=1, minutes=30)))
     )
```

3. Bin values into discrete intervals:

```
df1['interval'] = pd.cut(df1.index, bins=ii)
df2['interval'] = pd.cut(df2.index, bins=ii)
```

4. Merge the two dataframes on `interval`:

```
dfx = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='interval', how='left').set_index('interval')
dfx = (dfx['value_2'].lt(2800) & dfx['value_1'].gt(1600)) \
          .astype(int).to_frame('count').set_index(df2.index)
```

5. Append index of `df1` with as a freq of 90 minutes:

```
dti = df2.index.append(
          pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.index.to_series().resample('90T').groups.keys())
      ).sort_values().drop_duplicates()
dfx = dfx.reindex(dti).ffill().astype(int)
```

6. Compute duration from `count` and reindex from `df2`:

```
dfx['duration'] = dfx.index.to_series().diff(-1).abs() \
                     .fillna(pd.Timedelta(0)).dt.components \
                     .apply(lambda x: f"{x['hours']:02}:{x['minutes']:02}",
                            axis='columns')

dfx.loc[dfx['count'] == 0, 'duration'] = '00:00'
dfx = dfx.reindex(df2.index)
```

Output result:

```
>>> dfx
                     count duration
date_2
2017-10-11 00:00:00      1    00:30
2017-10-11 00:30:00      1    00:20
2017-10-11 00:50:00      1    00:30
2017-10-11 01:20:00      1    00:10
2017-10-11 01:40:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 02:20:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 02:50:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 03:00:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 03:20:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 03:50:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 04:20:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 04:50:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 05:20:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 05:50:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 06:00:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 06:20:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 06:50:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 07:20:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 07:50:00      1    00:30
2017-10-11 08:20:00      1    00:30
2017-10-11 08:50:00      1    00:10
2017-10-11 09:20:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 09:50:00      0    00:00
2017-10-11 10:20:00      0    00:00
```

Comment: Dear Corralien, thank you very much again for the kind help, as before. I am sorry that, there was slight mistake on my `df1` , now I have edited my `df1` . I think it will justify those `1` s , you are talking about.

Comment: @ Corralien , my bad! I did not notice that before. I have changed it now. Can you please check it?

Comment: For 08:50:00, explain me why 00:10?

Comment: time difference between 08:50:00 and the 09:00:00 ( the nearest reference timestamp of `df1`)is 00:10 and; similar is the difference between 01:30:00 and 01:20:00